Image crops when Scrolling ASP.NET MVC
I have an image cropping when data is more than the actual page (if that makes sense). When I scroll, I want the image to always be in the background regardless of whether it is being scrolled.
The red circle is the background image that is being cropped when scrolled. The green circle is an image for a particular product (it is longer than the page therefore scrolling is present). The purple circle (try saying that 5 times quickly), is the white space that I want filled with my background image.

This is what I have done so far:
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img-details {
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
 
.background-logo-login {
  isolation: isolate;
}

.background-logo-login::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-image: url(../img/SAS_web_2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background-attachment: fixed; */
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* background-size: fixed; */
  /* background-size: 100% 100vh; */
  background-size: cover;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  /* background-size: contain; */
}

ProductDetails.cshtml:
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 text-center">
            // Getting image from Azure Blob url
            <img class="img-details" src="@Model.ImageUrl" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            // Other code
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue. If you don't want to upload actual images somewhere we can access them as well, then use a service like https://placehold.co And don't show us your server-side template that will be filled with data we also do not have available, but an example of the resulting HTML code.

I found a solution to what I was trying to do. Even tho the background image had background-attachment: fixed; property for my background image it was still being scrolled when scrolling was present. The fix that I found was adding position: fixed; Making sure whatever the content is showing the content can be scrollable but not the background image.
In hindsight, this is what one line of code would do for me:

.background-logo-login::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.05;
  background-image: url(../img/SAS_web_2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed; <--Adding this will set the background image fixed no matter if scrolling was present or not
}


Hope this made sense!
